# Embedding images in a block from url

Tags: media, uri, nodes

How do I embed a URL in a block which is displayed as the linked image on the site?

Answer (score 0):

For any source or path of any thing in drupal site use src like this. It will work everywhere.

```
<?php $src = base_path() .'sites/files/logo.png'; ?>
```

This src use like

```
<img alt="logo" src=" <?php echo $src ; ?>">
```

Enable PHP filter module that come with core module.

and in Block Body Choose Text format as PHP CODE.

I assuming block is created using Block module(Block UI)

Comment: Ah thank you! But got to ask - where does the base path begin? On the server of the site or in the base folder of the server? Yes I'm new to this...

Immediately it just displays the code on the site rather than anything...

Comment: base_path() Returns the base URL path (i.e., directory) of the Drupal installation on server

Comment: So I write this:
<img alt="logo" src=" <?php echo $src ; ?>">
$src = base_path() .'files/lightwater.jpg';
(tried the other way around as well)

And this shows up in the block:
">
$src = base_path() .'files/lightwater.jpg';

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How to you build that block ? Any custom module, view, or Block UI?

Comment: Simply using the standard drupal 7 interface - no modules installed.

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer - rather easy really.... the module Image Block solves the whole problem for those of you who might see this post asking yourself the same question!

EDIT
The module simply creates an image block as said - it adds a "Add image block" to the block admin page. On the page you can choose to upload a picture - so you simply have to download the image from the URL and upload it in the block. 
Hence it does not exactly solve the problem but this is a workaround.

Comment: May you expand your answer to describe in which way those modules helped you?

Comment: I simply forgot to write "module" in front of the name :-) Pardon

Comment: You should describe how you used the module to solve your problem. I understood you were speaking of a module; that is not the problem. `:)`

Comment: Aight done - I had forgotten that you could only upload images to the block though... But it's a workaround for those with zero coding skills like me